# The term 'git' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,.. on Windows

Tags: powershell, path, config, integration, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm getting the below error

```
& : The term 'git' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the 
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Windows\TEMP\build_script770011073\script.ps1:217 char:3
+ & "git" "config" "-f" "C:\Gitlab-Runner\builds\CAxyhqeU\0\Main\aimoap
```

[image]
I have the below code that I'm using in my gitlab-ci.yml file

```
stages:
    - test

newman_tests:
    stage: test
    image:
        name: postman/newman
        entrypoint: [""]
    script:
        - newman --version
        - newman run ./Postman_Collections/APIAutomation.json
```

and my GITLAB URL is `https://gitlab.shared.pub.tds.*****.com/`
I have integrated my **Postman collection** with GITLAB using the Integration feature that Postman has provided.

What I'm missing over here? I don't think environment variables will come into the picture over here?

If it comes, then it will be for `gitlab-runner` and not GITLAB, right?
Let me know if you need any more details.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Unable to locate package git" when running GitLab CI/CD pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66005597/unable-to-locate-package-git-when-running-gitlab-ci-cd-pipeline)

Comment: Hi @AdamMarshall ,I tried understanding the best practices for the SHELL -https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/shell.html. My GITLAB is hosted on the server and gitlab-runner on my machine. GitLab is not the latest version. Is it due to which I'm facing the issue?

Comment: No, none of that will matter. The issue is simply that `git` is not installed in your image.

Comment: And how can I do that? Since I'm using Shell as the executor.

Comment: I assumed you’re using the docker executor since you have an image listed in your job. If you’re using shell, simply install git on the host running `gitlab-runner` and ensure it’s in a spot accessible to the runner.

Comment: I installed git on my Windows and tried executing the job, I'm still getting the same error. Do I need to install it at a specific location?

Answer (score 0):

Check the environment variables. The Git path need to be added in system variables. Normally, you may only have it added in the User variables which can not be used by git-runner, since you always run git-runner through Administrator privilege.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).