# Set dynamic depth for git fetch command

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

In my gitlab CI the last 50 commits are fetched by default. To change this I can use [extra flag](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/configure_runners.html#git-fetch-extra-flags) and the extra flag accepts all options of the [git fetch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) command.

For example I can change it to

```
variables:
    GIT_FETCH_EXTRA_FLAGS: --depth 100
```

With this the last 100 commits are fetched.

But I would like to fetch all commits since the last release (which in my case always has a tag). In my pipeline I'm already doing things like

```
- tag=$(git describe --tags --abbrev=0)
- base=$(git rev-parse $tag)
```

to get the commit with the last tag and I process this in the pipeline.

Is it possible to set the depth dynamically or maybe there is another option to use the last tag? Because if I set a 'hardcoded' depth value and there will be more commits at some time, the pipeline is failing.

Comment: Short answer: No. There is a `--shallow-since` option with a date, and there is `--depth` with a number, and that's it.

Comment: @torek But I could calculate the depth like `git rev-list 33b14c62b...33ad6cecf | wc -l`. Isn't it possible to do it in a way like this? Although I'm not sure, if I can calculate anything in this `variable` section...

Comment: You can calculate the depth needed for a clone, but to do that, you first need a clone that's deep enough to calculate the necessary depth. In which case ... why are you cloning?

Answer (score 2):

Your best option is to use the variable `GIT_STRATEGY: none` to tell the Runner not to clone/fetch the repository at all while setting up the job, and instead run your own git commands in your script section.

For example:

```yaml
...
A Job:
  stage: a_stage
  image: alpine:latest # super small image to promote quick CI pipelines
  variables:
    - GIT_STRATEGY: none
  before_script:
    - apk add git # See notes below
  script:
    - git ... # whatever you need to do
    - ...
```

Note: it's simplest to just install the packages you need in your CI jobs, but this will happen every single time the pipeline runs. It's better to [create a custom image based on the image you're using, install the packages you need there, and use that image in CI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66012365/2307873).

Comment: That's a great idea, but as far as I understand it now, the problem is, that I can't run a git command on remote repository to calculate the depth. I have to fetch the rep to do some calculation. But then I already fetched a big one, so it doesn't make sense

Comment: If you use the `GIT_STRATEGY: none` variable, your job is a blank slate so you should be able to do anything you need to in the script section, just like you could locally. Although I'm not too familiar with what you're trying to achieve, so I could be missing something.

Comment: Just to be sure, there is not a misunderstanding on my side: If I use `GIT_STRATEGY: none`, the job is blank, so there is no repository data fetched at all. If I do any git calculation to get the depth of the repository, it will always fail, as it is blank. So I would have to fetch the rep first, to do any calculations (like searching for the latest tag and its commit sha)

Comment: That's correct. All the runner will do is spin up the container and start executing your script. As a quick example from some of my pipelines, I have jobs that install dependencies, set up environment variables, package it all as a tarball and upload as an artifact. In my deploy jobs, I don't need the repo anymore, just the tarball, so I use this variable and pull down the artifact, then deploy.

Comment: Thanks, but at some time you need the repo to install deps and so on. And for this step the default depth for fetching is 50. So if there are more then 50 commits, the pipeline could be failing as my scripts need all commits since the last release (tag). Of course I can raise the depth to 300, but I thought of getting exactly the needed depth. As far as I understand it right not, it is not possible.

Comment: From your first comment, is the issue just that you can’t run these commands on a _remote_ repository? And if so, could you clone that repo?

Comment: I can clone the repo, but that doesn't give me an advantage, because then I have already processed a big amount of data, which is what I want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

This should cause fetch to not retrieve everything from 1.6.1 back.

Note: The commit for 1.6.1 itself will Not be fetched.

```
git fetch --shallow-exclude 1.6.1
```